# Node.js SSL authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, ssl

I set up a HTTPS node.js server, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use it correctly.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log('got in');
    if(req.client.authorized){
        res.send(200, 'certified');
    }else{
        res.send(200, 'idk who you are');
    }
});

require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, app).listen(8080);
```

What does the client have to do to be 'authorized' on my server?

I can browse to

```
https://localhost:8080/test
```

and it tells me that my certificate isn't trusted (that's okay, the SSL is self signed for now.). I proceed anyway but I always go to 'idk who you are', meaning the SSL authentication failed.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a step here.

P.S., if it is important, I am setting up SSL for encryption purposes.

Comment: req.client.authorized what is it? Perhaps it is undefined, that's why you always get 'idk who you are'.

Comment: it console logs to false

Answer (score 1):

The `authorized` property is false because the certificate provided by the client is not signed by a trusted certificate authority. Being as `rejectUnauthorized` is false, the connection is not rejected, rather it is marked as un-authorized.

See here -
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_tls_wrap.js#L512